# Does Sony SDK support RX10 IV?

Tags: api, sdk, camera, sony

Does anyone know if the Sony Camera Remote API SDK supports (or just happens to work with) the RX10 IV (DSC-RX10M4)?

It seems like it would, however, version 2.4 of the SDK (the current one) added support for the RX10 III (DSC-RX10M3) and the RX10 II (DSC-RSCM2) was already supported.

Thank you!

Comment: Currently the RX10 IV is not supported. I will let you know if this changes.

Comment: Thank you.I just realized that the RX10 IV can utilize PlayMemories Online, but does not have PlayMemories Camera App on the camera itself.

Answer (score 0):

i have developped an android app for myself and it is working great with the rx10m4.

The only thing that doesn't work so far is the Touch focus

Comment: Can you mention the API you have used and the documentation to it please?

Comment: I've also written an app that works with the RX10M4. The XML returned from the API's differed quite a bit from the responses from RX10M3, but they were all correct per the SDK documentation. The Sony API allows you to query the camera directly for the available API - just call getAvaailableApiList as per the documentation. For example my RX10M4 currently returns: getShootMode
getAvailableShootMode
getFlashMode
getAvailableFlashMode
getSupportedSelfTimer
getSupportedMovieQuality
startLiveview
stopLiveview
startMovieRec
stopMovieRec
actZoom
… Etc (many more).

Comment: I do wish Sony would update the firmware for the RX10M4, though. There are many features the M3 supported (like focus) that the M4 doesn't with the current firmware